# Does the client broadcast it's version? Is it possible to determine which version of client are in use?

Tags: client, protocol

When the client communicates to other clients does it transmit its version?  If so is it only on certain communications (i.e. originated transactions)?

Can this data be captured?  I would be interested to see if it is possible ot determine which versions are in use and hopefully combine that with geo-location data to map the bitcoin network by client node version.

Comment: please do it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you connect to the other Bitcoin client, the [first message you send is "version"](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#version), which states your protocol version. Moreover, it states both your IP address, and the addres you are connecting to. You can capture this data like any other [TCP/IP data](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/smsniff.html).